# C# & ASP.NET Core MVC : how to display "result" in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have problem with my code. Getting to the point I need to display "result" in view `ConvertCurrencies`. How can I do that? There is no problem with response from the server, 'result', 'currencyCodes' etc. contain results from server.

This is part of my code:

```
private const string nbpApiUrl = RatesExchangeServices.exchangeratesUrl;

        //Akcja wyświetlająca widok
        public IActionResult ConvertCurrencies()
        {
            //Pobiera listę kodów walut z metody
            var currencyCodes = GetCurrencyCodes();

            //Stworzenie SelectList z kodami walut
            var currencyList = new SelectList(currencyCodes);

            //Przekazanie SelectList do widoku
            ViewBag.currencyList = currencyList;

            return View();
        }
        
        //Akcja przeliczająca waluty
        
        public async Task<ActionResult> Convertion(string fromCurrency, string toCurrency, decimal amount)
        {
            //Pobieramy kursy walut
            var exchangeRate1 = await GetExchangeRateFrom(fromCurrency);
            var exchangeRate2 = await GetExchangeRateTo(toCurrency);

            //Przeliczamy kwotę
            var result = amount * exchangeRate1[fromCurrency] / exchangeRate2[toCurrency];

            //Zwracamy wynik w widoku

            ViewBag.result = result;    

            return View();
        }

        //Metoda pobierająca listę kodów walut
        private List<string> GetCurrencyCodes()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(nbpApiUrl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("tables/a").Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                    var currencies = new List<string>();

                    foreach (var rate in data[0].rates)
                    {
                        currencies.Add(rate.code.ToString());
                    }

                    return currencies;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Valid connection with Api.");
                }
            }
        }
        // Metoda[1] pobierająca kursy walut 
        private async Task<Dictionary<string, decimal>> GetExchangeRateFrom(string fromCurrency)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(nbpApiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"rates/a/{fromCurrency}/");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootDTO>(json);
                    var rates = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

                    foreach (var rate in data.rates)
                    {
                        rates[data.code] = Convert.ToDecimal(rate.mid);  
                    }

                    return rates;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Valid connection with Api.");
                }
            }
        }
        // Metoda[2] pobierająca kursy walut 
        private async Task<Dictionary<string, decimal>> GetExchangeRateTo(string toCurrency)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(nbpApiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"rates/a/{toCurrency}/");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootDTO>(json);
                    var rates = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

                    foreach (var rate in data.rates)
                    {
                        rates[data.code] = Convert.ToDecimal(rate.mid);
                    }
                    return rates;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Valid connection with Api.");
                }
            }
        }
```

And my view `ConvertCurrencies.cshtml`: I suppose that id=result should show me result but it doesn't. And what should I write in script (first braces I have "result" as you can see), because I suppose result is written wrong.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Currency Converter";
}

<h2>Twój lokalny kantor walut</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ConvertCurrencies", "currency", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Wymień z:")
        @Html.DropDownList("fromCurrency", (SelectList)ViewBag.currencyList, "Wybierz walutę")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Wymień do:")
        @Html.DropDownList("toCurrency", (SelectList)ViewBag.currencyList, "Wybierz walutę")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Ilość:")
        @Html.TextBox("amount")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Wynik konwersji:")
        <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Wymień" />
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("result").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#result").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I was trying a lot of variants but nothing worked.

Comment: `ViewBag` _is_ case-sensitive. So, this `ViewBag.currencyList` property is not the same as this `ViewBag.CurrencyList` property (notice the casing on the first 'C'). Be sure your view uses the same casing you used in the code.

Comment: fixed this one.

Comment: what should I do more with my code ?

Comment: You have to show your currency code class

Comment: Your ajax send an post request to your server, But i don't find any `HttpPost` action in the code you provided.

Comment: Pasted part of controller that refers to this page.

Comment: Another thing, in your JavaScript you need to set the submit on the form not on the span element; change this, `$("result").submit..` to this `$("myFormId").submit..`, and replace _myFormId_ with the name you give your form. Basically, when the submit button is clicked it needs to know what form to submit and you are giving it the span's id which it cannot submit as it's not a form.